# Replace string with element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div with some text 
`<div>This is my initial text</div>`
And I'd like to replace the text 'initial' with an input box which I already have created

Something like:

```
input=$("#myinput");
$("div").find("initial").replaceWith(input);
```

OR:

```
input=$("#myinput");
$("div").html().replace('initial',input);
```

But neither of these work

Any thoughts?

Comment: `var inputString = document.createElement('div').appendChild(input[0]).innerHTML;`. With the input as a string you can do a normal replace.

Comment: What? Won't that work? It's even Vanilla JS. @SpikeX

Comment: @11684 OP wants to take **only the word 'initial'** from within the `<div>` he's posted, and replace it with a text box. So the resulting HTML should be `<div>This is my <input type="text" /> text</div>`.

Comment: The code in my comment produces a string (`"<input type=\"text\" />"`). The only reason why the OP's code didn't work was that he was trying to use jQuery object instead of a string. @SpikeX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var input = $("#myinput");
$("div:contains(initial)").replaceWith(input);
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuq6e/)

**EDIT:**

to replace just the word "initial" :

```
var input = $("#myinput");
$("div:contains(initial)").html(function(_,html) {
     return html.replace('initial', input.get(0).outerHTML);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tuq6e/1/)

Comment: How many times do I have to post this comment in this thread: *I believe he only wants to replace the word "initial", not the whole thing.*

Comment: @SpikeX - That's even easier ?

Comment: I wouldn't call it "easier" if it's three lines instead of two. ;)

Comment: Maybe not easier, but not very hard either, and I did'nt even add elements to the markup.

Comment: Great! outer.HTML is what I was looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Why not surround it with a span so that it's easier to find:

```
<div>This is my <span id="replace">initial</span> text</div>
```

Then:

```
$('#replace').replaceWith(input);
```

Comment: That's pretty freaking amazing, three upvoters doesn't know that javascripts `replace()` method only works on strings, and not on jQuery elements ?

Comment: @adeneo Ha! Good catch, should have been `.replaceWith()`. Fixed!

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$("div").html($('div').text().replace('initial',input.html()));
```

Though I like this better if your jQuery is new enough:

```
$("div").html($.parseHTML($('div').text().replace('initial',input.html())));
```

Comment: You like the longer one better...?

Comment: Um, that going to say something like [Object object]

Comment: @SpikeX The value passed to the .html() function begins with plain text and not not text containing a tag--like `<div>...`

Answer (score -2):

This ought to work:

```
$("div").html(input)
```

**EDIT**: actually, no, it won't, you need to wrap "initial" with some sort of element, preferably with an "id" or "class" element so you can select it directly.

**EDIT #2**:

```
// Grab the actual HTML of the element you want to inject
var elementHTML = $(input).html();

// Loop over each DIV, though you really should use ID/class attributes
$("div").each(function() {
    var divHTML = $(this).html(); // Grab a copy of the DIV's HTML
    $(this).html(divHTML.replace('initial', elementHTML)); // Replace "initial" in the saved string with the element's HTML from above
});
```

Comment: I believe he only wants to replace the word "initial", not the whole thing.

Comment: This won't preserve the rest of the string.

Comment: Yeah, realized that as soon as I posted it.

Comment: It's okay, man, we all make mistakes ... just hit delete and move on. That's what it's there for. :)

Comment: I live with my mistakes. Trying to figure out a method where they wouldn't have to modify the HTML, in case that's a constraint.

Comment: Yeah, but you've got to remember that if someone comes across this post in the future, they should only see answers that are correct / helpful. The "proper" thing to do would be to delete and if you find another solution, post another answer at that time. I delete my answers all the time if I'm wrong, it's not about pride.

Comment: True, but deletion isn't mandatory either (though it's likely that wrong answers will continue to garner down-votes as time goes on, so non-deletion becomes masochistic after a while).

Comment: Meh, they're imaginary points. If I can't come up with a solution, I'll delete a post. If, on the other hand, like here, I come up with a correct solution, it might be helpful to see the thought process in figuring out the correct answer.